# laravel variable not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is weird. I am sure I am missing something simple. I have the following code:

```
$productToken = Input::get('key');
        $products = new Product;
        $userEmail = $products->activateProduct($productToken);

        $productDetailsArray = $products->getProductDetailsForUserEmail($productToken);

        $emailData = $productDetailsArray;
        Mail::send('emails.productReleased', $emailData, function($message){
            $message->to($userEmail)->subject('Notification - Your Product was Released to the Public!');
        });
```

It is supposed to activate the product in the database and then send email to user. The email of the user is in the $userEmail and when I did var_dump, it shows. Somehow this line throws an error that $userEmail is undefined:

```
$message->to($userEmail)->subject('Notification - Your Product was Released to the Public!');
```

This is the error I get:

```
Undefined variable: userEmail
```

I used Mail function before but instead of passing variable I passed the Input::get('email') because it was in a registration form. Right now, I don't have access to the Input but rather $userEmail. Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a callback so function so at the time the function is called, the `userEmail` variable is certainly out of scope. You should send the `userEmail` variable to the function, maybe like this :

```
Mail::send('emails.productReleased', $emailData, function($message) use ($userEmail) {
    $message->to($userEmail)->subject('Notification - Your Product was Released to the Public!');
});
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php#example-191 for information about lambda (anonymous) function and context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your `$userEmail` variable to the closure scope by using `use`.

`function($message) use ($userEmail)`

For more infos using anonymous functions take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php)